# PHP password_hash how to check?

Tags: php

I try a new function of PHP called "password_hash". I want to have just one password to check if it's equal to the static password. If the password equal then I want to go to the other page.

This is the code how I try it:

```
    $gen_pass  =    password_hash("test", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    if(isset($_POST["submit_verify"]))
    {
         $pass_verify = filter_var($_POST["pass_verify"], 
         FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
         if($pass_verify)
         {
             if(password_verify($pass_verify, $gen_pass))
                echo "<h1>SUCCESS</h1>";

             else 
                header("location: ../index");
        }
    else $error_msg     =   "Error!";
}
```

But when I try it then the site are refreshing and nothing happens.
And when I write in the input the wrong password then I'm successful on the index.php page.

Comment: but index location in else condition

Comment: maybe just because of {} just an idea. add {} for else

Comment: @devpro thx that was the mistake...
I remember that sometimes I can the { } remove it but it works now :)

Comment: thats good, actually there are some extra spaces arounf IF ELSE so i suggest to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$options  = [ 'cost' => 12 ];
$gen_pass = password_hash( "test", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options );
    if(isset($_POST["submit_verify"]))
    {
         if( password_verify( $_POST[ "submit_verify" ], $gen_pass ) )
         {
                if( password_needs_rehash( 'password_from_database', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $this->cost ) )
                {
                  $new_hashed_password = password_hash( "new_password", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options );
                  // Run and update script to update the password in the database
                }
                echo "<h1>SUCCESS</h1>";
         }
         else 
         {             
                header("location: ../index");
         }
    }
```

From what I can tell using `$pass_verify = filter_var($_POST["pass_verify"], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);` will remove and replace `<>` and `&` what happens if the password contains those characters?

To determine your optimal cost you could use a function like this, the returned number is the cost value to use for the amount of time it takes.  Change the `$min_ms` to however long you want and it will provide a cost for you.  This is taken from the PHP password_hash page.

```
function getOptimalBcryptCostParameter($min_ms = 1000) {
    for ($i = 4; $i < 31; $i++) {
        $options = [ 'cost' => $i ];
        $time_start = microtime(true);
        password_hash("PASSWORD_HERE", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
        $time_end = microtime(true);
        echo "Time to hash: ".($time_end - $time_start).' with a  cost of '.$i.'<br>';
        if (($time_end - $time_start) * 1000 > $min_ms) {
            return $i;
        }
    }
}
echo getOptimalBcryptCostParameter(); // prints 12 in my case
```

Comment: hey, thx i try it, it works too. I have two methods, the first don't forget the { } and the 2. method which you postet. Thank you too for your help :)

Comment: Great, glad your up and running.

Comment: but wait I changed the password and now I get the page index.php and not the echo Text... What means "cost" and the number "12"?

Comment: For cost start reading from here - http://php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php . As for the password change, how did you change your password.  Did you use the password_hash() function or have you manually changed it in the database to a plain text password?

Comment: I only change in this case the password: "password_hash( "test", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options );"

Comment: Have a look at the answer, I have added the `password_needs_rehash()` function.  If you where to change the cost or encryption type then this will update the databases stored password.  You will need to run the update script on the ID that you collected when you searched for the user by email.

Comment: Okey I understand but it works just when I get the Password from the Database? Because I'm try to make a simply login without the Database. For the login I try to make one password which is everytime hashed and when I fill it in the form then I'm logged in...
Or I'm think now wrong?

Comment: Your trying to make a login system without a database?? Not sure that is something thats going to work so well.

Comment: Hmmm okey then it's no problem then I change it to get the data from the Database. Maybe you can help me, I would like to create an extra page where just one passwort will be accept, should i work with the Database just for one key? I'm in PHP advanced but I have no Idea how can I make it simply... Thats why I'm ask if there any methods for that because for just one key get it from the data?

Comment: Mate I will not be writting the code for you, google "Simple php mysql login page", here one example - http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL